# Firebase database Authentication phone Permission denied

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm try to write app and i have some security issue that I cant solve and I need help.
I'm using user phone authentication on firebase and it's working ok. Now I wants when user auth is granted the user id save on database and it's working .

But the problem is the rules I use this code for write on database for new user:

```
{
  "rules": {

      ".write": "auth == null ",
      ".read": "auth == null "              
  }
}
```

this code is for when new user register:

```
  FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
   Firebase Ref = new Firebase( "database address" );
     Firebase usersRef = Ref.child( "Users" ).child( "user_id" );
       usersRef.setValue( user.getUid() );
```

when i use this rule Authentication denied  :

```
{
  "rules": {

      ".write": "auth != null ",
      ".read": "auth != null "              
  }
}
```

but my user already is registered and i get his id and phone form Authentication user how can i solve this security issue ?

```
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( b3bizXzmH7XQfXWNvHCMVXzDHSx2 ).
D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.
D/PhoneAuthActivity: signInWithCredential:success
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( b3bizXzmH7XQfXWNvHCMVXzDHSx2 ).
D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
               Notified 0 auth state listeners.
D/PhoneAuthActivity: signInWithCredential:success
W/RepoOperation: setValue at /Users/user_id failed: FirebaseError: Permission denied
W/RepoOperation: setValue at /Users/user_id failed: FirebaseError: Permission denied
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( b3bizXzmH7XQfXWNvHCMVXzDHSx2 ).
D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.
D/PhoneAuthActivity: signInWithCredential:success
W/RepoOperation: setValue at /Users/user_id failed: FirebaseError: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
{
"rules": {

  ".write": "auth == true",
  ".read": "auth == true"              
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond but the problem was from my code i solved it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem the answer:

```
   FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
          mDatabase =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                 String current_uid =user.getUid();
                mDatabase.child( "Users" ).child( "uid" ).setValue( current_uid );
```